# Bigquery google auth without browser prompt

Tags: python, google-bigquery

i am accessing user data by connecting to bigquery via python with OAuth 2.0 method. But every time I make a query, it repeatedly asks for browser confirmation. How can I cancel this verification? When I set the launch_browser value to False, it requests confirmation from the terminal. Is there a different method I can use? I am using the same sample code found in the document https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/end-user-installed

```
from google_auth_oauthlib import flow
from google.cloud import bigquery

launch_browser = True
appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    "client_secrets.json", scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
)
if launch_browser:
    appflow.run_local_server()
else:
    appflow.run_console()
credentials = appflow.credentials
project = 'user-project-id'
client = bigquery.Client(project=project, credentials=credentials)
query_string = """SELECT name, SUM(number) as total
FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
WHERE name = 'William'
GROUP BY name;
"""
query_job = client.query(query_string)
for row in query_job.result(): 
    print("{}: {}".format(row["name"], row["total"]))
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the `browser confirmation` you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Storing the credentials in a file stops google from constantly requesting it, it only lasts for a little while though.

```
creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_console()
        #creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
```

This is what I use to load credentials (I do mine through console as it is on Linux with no browser)

You may have to change some parts to fit your code but this is the general idea.